# ASP.NET Deployment Tool

Tags: asp.net, deployment, automation

Before I re-invent the wheel I wanted to see if a similar tool already existed. I want to automate the deployment of our various web sites, web services & multiple databases.

I was thinking of writing a NAnt script and a simple GUI application which would enumerate the targets within the NAnt script and show a list of tasks which could then be toggled on/off and executed. Does such a tool already exist?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MsDeploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2008/01/23/msdeploy-exe-tool-for-content-replication-sync-iis-settings-and-more.aspx) and the [Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/) I would use MSBuild to tie them all together though.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) in the past. They have a [.NET flavor](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) for it as well. For us, the setup/config was long, but once it was all set, it worked pretty well.